# Why is powershell opening notepad instead of vscode?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Running `explorer .` opens an explorer windows

[image]

However, running `code .` for vscode opens *code.cmd* with a bunch of args.

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happenining? and a possible rememdy?

Comment: What happens when you start (double-click) the file manually?

Comment: If cmd files are opening in Notepad its likely due to the default application configuration for that file type - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs-in-windows-10-e5d82cad-17d1-c53b-3505-f10a32e1894d

Comment: @marsze pressing the start menu shortcut opens code normally

Comment: I was talking about the `code.cmd` file

Comment: Check if the install directory for VS Code is in your PATH environment variable. By default this is `C:\users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`. In your case, find the correct path by selecting "Open file location" from the menu shortcut. See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_common-questions)

Comment: @marsze I am unsure whether the code.cmd file was explicitly saved anywhere. I cannot verify it either. After the fix I cannot reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @Theo I verified that vscode was indeed in the my PATH variable. Thanks!

Comment: check `Get-Command code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Have you tried restarting it?

Restarting the machine (first in safe mode) and then normal mode solved the issue.

**Note**: *Default apps* (still) associates the .cmd extension with notepad but this doesn't prevent expected behavior.